# Rails storing host password for FTP model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, ftp, passwords

I'm building a rails app that communicates with other servers via ftp.  The user needs to input their host, username and password for their particular ftp server.  I wouldn't want to store their password as cleartext, but I need the actual password to connect to the server when it comes time.  Would it make sense to use a two-way hash?

I found a few implementations that might do the job:
http://crypt.rubyforge.org/blowfish.html
[http://crypt.rubyforge.org/rijndael.html](http://crypt.rubyforge.org/blowfish.html)
http://ezcrypto.rubyforge.org/

Thanks,
Trevor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since password is eventually passed to the FTP server as cleartext, *any* db encryption is a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [attr_encrypted](http://github.com/shuber/attr_encrypted) which worked great.